# MS Access - How to change the linked table path by amend the table

Tags: ms-access, linked-tables

Below query allow me to show all linked table and its corresponding database path

```
SELECT DISTINCTROW msysobjects.Name, msysobjects.Database, msysobjects.Connect
FROM msysobjects WHERE (((msysobjects.Type)=6 Or (msysobjects.Type) Like "dsn*")) ORDER BY msysobjects.Database;
```

Output

```
Name                    Database                             Connect
Account Transactions    C:\Users\Desktop\Database6_be.accdb 
Categories              C:\Users\Desktop\Database6_be.accdb 
Filters                 C:\Users\Desktop\Database6_be.accdb 
tblAuditLog             C:\Users\Desktop\Database6_be.accdb
```

As i renamed the database for particular 2 tables, while i unable to amend the path. Is there any way i can amend the linked table path by amend the table?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can either do it through VBA, or through the GUI

Through the GUI (Access 2010):

[image]

You can use the following VBA sub to change the connection strings on certain tables (you need to provide both the old and new connection string):

```vb
Public Sub ChangeConnection(OldStr As String, NewStr As String)
    Dim td As DAO.TableDef
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Set db = CurrentDb()
    For Each td In db.TableDefs
        With td
            If .Connect = OldStr Then
                .Connect = NewStr
                .RefreshLink
            End If
        End With
    Next td
End Sub
```

Or, you can use the following sub to change one specific table

```vb
Public Sub ChangeTableConnection(Tablename As String, NewStr As String)
    Dim td As DAO.TableDef
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Set db = CurrentDb()
    Set td = db.TableDefs(Tablename)
    td.Connect = NewStr
    td.RefreshLink
End Sub
```

Comment: Work like a charm!