# Systematically/automatically find the changed path of a linked table in access based criteria

Tags: vba, ms-access, linked-tables

My first question ever, not sure how the forum really works so please correct any noob-behavior. Here is what I am after:

1. I have an access database with several (+30) linked files.
2. Every month, I rename each of those linked files to prepare for the next month using powershell
3. The links in the access database disappear and I have to re-link them manually :(

Is there a way to systematically/automatically find not just the changed path of a linked table in access but to do it based on a monthly drumbeat? For instance, in March, I know they will need to be renamed "3+9 Files", in April, "4+8 files", and so on.

Any ideas? I'm relatively versed in VBA, basic SQL. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've shared several ways to relink tables, both manually and programmatically, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47283914/7296893). If you have a specific question, I can provide a specific answer.

Comment: For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the site.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth Ok, I will check out your information Erik, thank you very much.

Comment: @wazz thanks for the info Wazz, I'll check out the documentation and take site tour!